# Client Web part disappear from the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a web part client. I published it on my web site, but after some time, it disappeared from the page. I checked the latest  edition date of the pages, and this wasn't edited.

Thanks for your colaboration.​

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
?contents=1 (to your URL after .aspx)
```

Do you see your web part in there?
Also, check the Recycle bin

```
/_layouts/AdminRecycleBin.aspx
```